# Text appears after "pspicture" section even when it's inserted above it. How to preserve order?

Tags: pstricks

I want the heading "SCALENE TRIANGLE" to appear above the diagram. But that is not what happens, even if the text is inserted above the section.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
    \section{Triangles}
    \subsection{Scalene Triangle}
    \newline
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)
        \pspolygon(1,1)(3,4)(9,1)   %triangle
        \psline[linestyle=dashed](3,4)(3,1) %height
        \pspolygon(3,1)(3,1.2)(3.2,1.2)(3.2,1)  %right angle
        \uput{0.1}[180](1,1){A}
        \uput{0.1}[90](3,4){B}
        \uput{0.1}[0](9,1){C}
        \uput{0.2}[0](6,2.5){a}
        \uput{0.2}[270](5,1){b}
        \uput{0.2}[180](2,2.5){c}
        \uput{0.2}[0](3,2.5){h}
    \end{pspicture} 
    $$area = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},\quad s = \frac{(a+b+c)}{2}$$
    \subsection{Right Angled Triangle}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**OLD CODE PLEASE IGNORE**

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
    SCALENE TRIANGLE
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)
    \pspolygon(1,1)(3,4)(9,1)   %triangle
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](3,4)(3,1) %height
    \pspolygon(3,1)(3,1.2)(3.2,1.2)(3.2,1)  %right angle
    \uput{0.1}[180](1,1){A}
    \uput{0.1}[90](3,4){B}
    \uput{0.1}[0](9,1){C}
    \uput{0.2}[0](6,2.5){a}
    \uput{0.2}[270](5,1){b}
    \uput{0.2}[180](2,2.5){c}
    \uput{0.2}[0](3,2.5){h}
\end{pspicture}
    $$area = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},\quad s = \frac{(a+b+c)}{2}$$
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Inserting a blank line between the heading and the environment should be enough.

Comment: you have specified `(0,0)` so the pspicture takes up no space, and you have used positive coordinates so it over-prints anything above it.

Comment: @Bernard Inserting `\\newline` after section or subsection yields this error: `There's no line here to end. \subsection{Scalene Triangle}\\n`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\begin{pspicture}(0,5)` solved it. But is there a better way to do it? I am a n00b.

Comment: I mentioned a blank line, that's all, but there was no section in your initial post. You should give the dimensions of the pspicture. Also, don't use `$$ ... $$` for displayed equation: this is plain TeX syntax, and  it produces bad spacing with LateX. Use `\[ ... \]`instead.

Comment: `(0,5)` Is still making overprint. You are specifying everything by coordinate so specifying the natural size of the picture would be more usual. Also use `\mathit{area}` never use the default math font of words, it is designed to make adjacent letters look separated like a product of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a shorter code with `pst-eucl`, which is dedicated to plane geometry. No coordinates calculations are required – only the coordinates of A, B,C are used:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{FiraMono}

\begin{document}

\section{Triangles}
\subsection{Scalene Triangle}
\begin{center}
    \begin{pspicture*}(0.5,0.5)(9.5,4.5)
        \psset{PointSymbol = none, RightAngleSize = 0.2, linecolor = NavyBlue}
        \pstTriangle[PosAngle = {180,90,0}](1,1){A}(3,4){B}(9,1){C} %triangle
        \pstProjection[CodeFig, linewidth = 0.4pt, CodeFigColor = Tomato]{A}{C}{B}[H]\naput{$ h $}
        \psset{linestyle = none, labelsep = 2pt}
        \ncline{B}{C}\naput{$a$}
        \ncline{C}{A}\naput{$b$}
        \ncline{A}{B}\naput{$c$}
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{center}
\[ \text{area} = √{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},\quad s = \frac{a+b+c}{2} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the optional argument `[showgrid]`. Then you'll see what rectangle 
you have reserved for the image. If everything is fine, set `showgrid=false`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \section{Triangles}
    \subsection{Scalene Triangle}

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,5)
    \pspolygon(1,1)(3,4)(9,1)   %triangle
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](3,4)(3,1) %height
    \pspolygon(3,1)(3,1.2)(3.2,1.2)(3.2,1)  %right angle
    \uput{0.1}[180](1,1){A}
    \uput{0.1}[90](3,4){B}
    \uput{0.1}[0](9,1){C}
    \uput{0.2}[0](6,2.5){a}
    \uput{0.2}[270](5,1){b}
    \uput{0.2}[180](2,2.5){c}
    \uput{0.2}[0](3,2.5){h}
    \end{pspicture} 

    \[\textrm{area} = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},\quad s = \frac{(a+b+c)}{2}\]

    \subsection{Right Angled Triangle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `showgrid` is an amazing tip thank you! Now I can clearly see what space the picture is occupying.